# Click does not work after setting the setting the id in span inside the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 1 page profile and split it into 3 parts. My code does not seem to work properly. 
When I click "next" from the first page, it goes fine to the second page.  But I cannot seem to return to the page page by clicking previous.  Likewise I cannot seem to go to the third page and from the third page to previous page(page 2).

Any idea why?

```js
           $('#page1').show();
           $('#page2').hide();
           $('#page3').hide();


$(document).on('click', '#last', function() {
                  $('#page3').show();
                  $('#page1').hide();
                  $('#page2').hide();
                  $('#profile-prev').show();
        }); 



        $(document).on('click', '#prev1', function() {
                  $('#page1').show();
                  $('#page2').hide();
                  $('#page3').hide();
                  $('#prev1').hide();
                  $('#profile-next').show();
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page1"> page 1 </div>

<div id="page2"> page 2 </div>


<div id="page3"> page 3 </div>


<div id="profile-nav" style="width:400px; text-align:right; right:10px;;">
 <span id="profile-prev" style="color:#000; cursor:pointer;">Previous</span>
 <span> | </span>
 <span id="profile-next" style="color:#000; cursor:pointer;">Next</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean, does it stay at home all day watching daytime TV ?

Comment: LOL... @adeneo updated the question.. sorry

Answer (score 2):

#last and #prev1 do not exist on page load, so `.click()` function does not recoginze them.
You can use `.on()`:

```
$(document).on('click', '#last', function() {
   $('#page3').show();
   $('#page1').hide();
   $('#page2').hide();

   $('#profile-prev').show();
});
```

the same way with `#prev1`

Comment: I updated the question with your code. On the 1st page when I click 'next' it goes to the 3rd page which is wrong. but when the code is $(document) is removed it goes correctly to the 2nd page.